# What default PostgreSql password?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, postgresql

I tried use `docker` just install this docker container https://hub.docker.com/r/mdillon/postgis/ 
run this command from manual:

```
docker run --name some-postgis -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d mdillon/postgis
```

And now wnat to enter in `psql`:

```
su postgres
```

ANd i just can not login. I always thoght that `postgres` is default password but it not allow this.

What i can miss there?

Comment: Did you try `sudo su - postgres`?

Answer (score 5):

There isn’t a default password. The default authentication mode for PostgreSQL is set to ident, not to sql DB user/password.

Running `cat /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/pg_hba.conf` will show you that.

What that actually means is that in order correctly connect to PostgreSQL you must be logged in as the correct OS user that was used to install it. You practically authenticate with the OS user.